# Python hex/int/bin converter throws error

Tags: python, input, integer, hex, bin

As title says, I am trying to make a simple hex, int, and binary number converter in python. Here is my code:

```
numberToConvert=int(input("Enter a number? "))
base=int(input("Base of the number? "))
toConvertBase = int(input("Base wanted? "))

if base==2:
    if toConvertBase==2:
        print("Error: Same base.") #works
    elif toConvertBase==10:
        result=int(numberToConvert)
        print(f"Result is {result}")
    elif toConvertBase==16:
        result=hex(numberToConvert)
        print(f"Result is {result[2:]}")
elif base==10: #base10 works
    if toConvertBase==10:
        print("Error: Same base.")
    elif toConvertBase==16:
        numberToConvert=int(numberToConvert)
        result=hex(numberToConvert)
        print(f"Result is {result[2:]}")
    elif toConvertBase==2:
        numberToConvert=int(numberToConvert)
        result=bin(numberToConvert)
        print(f"Result is {result[2:]}")
elif base==16:
    if toConvertBase==16:
        print("Error: Same base.") #works
    elif toConvertBase==10:
        numberToConvert=hex(numberToConvert)
        result=int(numberToConvert)
        print(f"Result is {result}")
    elif toConvertBase==2:
        numberToConvert=hex(numberToConvert)
        result=bin(numberToConvert)
        print(f"Result is {result[2:]}")
else:
    print("Error: Not a supported base")
```

Base 10 to other bases conversions work well, but conversions from base 2 and 16 throw me this kind of errors each time:

```
Enter a number? 38
Base of the number? 16
Base wanted? 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vortex\Desktop\converter.py", line 34, in <module>
    result=bin(numberToConvert)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I don't know why this error appears as, at line 1 my input is converted to an int. I am doing something wrong but I don't know what, can someone help me please? Thank you

Comment: `hex` return a `str` type. see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex

Answer (score 0):

See below.
First you need to read the numberToConvert as string, to allow inputs like '3A' which is a valid number in hex.
After reading the number convert it to int, using 'base', and after that conversion to bin/int/hex is straightforward.

Then I've simplified a little the code.

```
numberToConvertStr=str(input("Enter a number? "))
base=int(input("Base of the number? "))
toConvertBase = int(input("Base wanted? "))

numberToConvert = int(numberToConvertStr, base)

if not (base in [2, 10, 16]):
    print("Error: Base {} not supported.".format(base))
    exit(0)
if base == toConvertBase:
    print("Error: Same base.")
    exit(0)


if toConvertBase==2:
    result=bin(numberToConvert)[2:]
elif toConvertBase==10:
    result=numberToConvert # already base 10
elif toConvertBase==16:
    result = hex(numberToConvert)[2:]
else:
    print("Error: Base {} not supported".format(toConvertBase))
    exit(0)

print(f"Result is {result}")
```

sample output

```
Enter a number? 3A
Base of the number? 16 
Base wanted? 10
Result is 58
```